# How to make pg_dump skip extension?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, pg-dump

This is on 9.3 but I can remember simillar things happening since 7.x. So I create database and install plpgsql extension into it. Later on I create a pg_dump and before restoring it into databse I make sure it also has plpgsql extension. Then when restoring this happens:

```
pg_restore: creating EXTENSION plpgsql
pg_restore: creating COMMENT EXTENSION plpgsql
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2053; 0 0 COMMENT EXTENSION plpgsql
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  must be owner of extension plpgsql
Command was: COMMENT ON EXTENSION plpgsql IS 'PL/pgSQL procedural language';
```

I'm creating a bunch of scripts and it's pretty important for me that pg_restore returns 0, so the fact that I can just ignore this isn't doing any good. What puzzles me is that IIRC I need to create extension as postgres master user, so I have no idea why all this EXTENSION stuff ends up in my dump. After all, I'm not owner of the language/extension?

Anyway, I'd be gratefull for any suggestion how to get rid of this. Please note, that I'm aware how the -l/-L switches work. This however seems to be way too much effort to correct just one simple extension comment.

Comment: FWIW, this has been reported last year and discussed as [bug #8695](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/E1VuYH7-0008Rz-SV@wrigleys.postgresql.org).

Answer (score 10):

For anyone looking for a workaround, limiting `pg_restore` to a specific schema has helped me get around this bug. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11776053/11819

Comment: I still had issues with extensions when I used the `-n` flag

Answer (score 6):

You can do

```
pg_dump ... | grep -v -E '^(CREATE\ EXTENSION|COMMENT\ ON)' >out.sql
```

it's what i use to import to google cloud sql with postgres.

edit: added 'start of line' caret to not exclude lines that contain this literal text.

Comment: that might remove record that contain that text, unlikely to happen, but you'll going to have a corrupted schema with missing constraints (as they are added at the end of the snapshot). I'd prefix a "--" instead of removing, and also considering  the DROP case

`pg_dump | sed 's/DROP EXTENSION/-- DROP EXTENSION/g' | sed 's/CREATE EXTENSION/-- CREATE EXTENSION/g' | sed 's/COMMENT ON EXTENSION/-- COMMENT ON EXTENSION/g'`

Answer (score 5):

Use the `-L` flag with pg_restore after taking a dump in a custom file format.

> -L *`list-file`*
> --use-list=*`list-file`*
>
> Restore only those archive elements that are listed in *`list-file`*, and restore them in the order they appear in the file. Note that if filtering switches such as `-n` or `-t` are used with `-L`, they will further restrict the items restored.
>
> *`list-file`* is normally created by editing the output of a previous `-l` operation. Lines can be moved or removed, and can also be commented out by placing a semicolon (`;`) at the start of the line.[...]

<sub>***Reference:** [pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/app-pgrestore.html) (PostgreSQL Documentation 9.3)*</sub>

```
pg_dump -Fc -f pg.dump db_name
pg_restore -l pg.dump | grep -v 'COMMENT - EXTENSION' | \
    grep -v 'plpgsql' > pg_restore.list
pg_restore --use-list pg_restore.list pg.dump
```

Here you can see the **Inverse** is true:

```
pg_dump -Fc -f pg.dump db_name
pg_restore -l pg.dump | grep 'COMMENT - EXTENSION' | grep 'plpgsql' > pg_restore.list
pg_restore --use-list pg_restore.list pg.dump
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 9.4.15
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 9.5.14

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

--
-- Name: EXTENSION plpgsql; Type: COMMENT; Schema: -; Owner: 
--

COMMENT ON EXTENSION plpgsql IS 'PL/pgSQL procedural language';


--
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
--
```

- (edited to add the second -v to the grep filter)

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. We appreciate your contribution. The original question is about PostgreSQL version 9.3., but your original answer was referencing the 9.5. version. I have modified your answer slightly to reflect that. However, parts of the output could be version specific and might be different in version 9.3.

Comment: This technique worked for me however the filtering command has an error. There should be `-v` in the `grep 'plpgsql'` command or else your `pg_restore.list` will contain *only* the `CREATE EXTENSION` command

Answer (score 1):

In order to export just the schema without any other objects of the database, you can specify the name of the schema using the parameter `--schema`

```
pg_dump --schema=<schema_name> --schema-only <db_name>
```

Comment: and also no data